# @Output in angular 2 doesn't work

Tags: angular-cli

I'm using Angular 2. So children component is

```
import { Component, OnInit,  Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
...
    export class EnterComponent implements OnInit {

        @Output() isClosedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
        public isClosed: boolean;

        constructor() {
            let isClose = true;
         }

        Close() {
            this.isClosed = false;
            this.isClosedChange.emit(this.isClosed);
        }
    }
```

my parent componet is

```
export class AppComponent {

    public isClosedinMain: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.isClosedinMain = true;

    }
}
```

and html:

```
<app-header (isClosedChange) = "isClosedinMain"></app-header>
```

It is very simple but *isClosedinMain* doesn't receive anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are binding to events use functions:

```
<app-header (isClosedChange) = "ClosedInMainFN($event)"></app-header>
```

and the in main component ts write function

```
ClosedInMainFN(event: boolean) {

this.isClosedinMain = event;

}
```

Comment: thank you! could you please tell me, why [(isClosedChange)]="isClosedinMain" works without any functions?

Comment: From angular.io: The framework passes the event argument—represented by $event—to the handler method, and the method processes it. Link:  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event. If you don't want to use method handler you could "emit" observable from child, and subscribe in parent with | async ...

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event [(isClosedChange) is a two way binding, and framework did job for you. If you use [] it is expected that receiver is input also.